# make a background work on all iphones ios

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I've just begun playing around with XCode and currently reading on Objective-C!

I have made a dark background and a book-ish "background" on top of it. Example [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swrlZ.png).

But how do I set it in a constant position on every iOS device and every iPhone screen-sizes?

Comment: How are you positioning it in the first place? In code or in IB (xib or storyboard)? Are you using Auto Layout or Autoresizing masks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of your image I assume that you want it to be fixed to the bottom.

To do that place your image view in the bottom of its superview and change the autosizing to be fixed to the bottom like in this image below.

The little red box in the view labeled "example" shows you how the image view will behave when the superview is resized.

[image]

If you want your image view to have a constant position anywhere else, just position it where you want it and set the appropriate autosizing for it (once again, look at the red box to see how it will behave when resized).

---

If the right pane is not visible press the right pane button in the tool bar (image below) or use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⎇</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> to display the right pane or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⎇</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> to go directly to the size inspector.

[image]

Comment: I dont seem to have that autosizing-part of the panel?

Comment: In the top right of your screen you see three buttons that look like "left," "bottom", "right"... press the right one. You can also press ⌘+⎇+0 to show the right pane or ⌘+⎇+5 to go directly to the size inspector

Comment: Ah, you are using auto layout then... You should see a lot of small blue lines that are the constraints (for things like size and position).

Comment: You can enable or disable autolayout from the left most tab in the right pane (the File inspector ⌘+⎇+1). Under "Interface Builder Document" there is a checkbox labeled "Use Autolayout"

Comment: Okei, but should i make two different images or use another technique to implement the picture? since it becomes too big for 3,5 inch if i adjust the hight to 4 inch screen?